# npm install gaves me npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, abp

i tried everything updated node angular restarted pc did all possible stuff but still get this error and i dont know why.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=12.0.0" from @abp/ng.account.core@5.3.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@abp/ng.account.core
npm ERR!     @abp/ng.account.core@"~5.3.4" from @abp/ng.account@5.3.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@abp/ng.account
npm ERR!       @abp/ng.account@"~5.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @abp/ng.account.core@"~5.3.4" from @abp/ng.theme.basic@5.3.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@abp/ng.theme.basic
npm ERR!       @abp/ng.theme.basic@"~5.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   peer @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@">=10.0.0" from @abp/ng.components@5.3.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@abp/ng.components
npm ERR!     @abp/ng.components@"~5.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@abp/ng.setting-management)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@14.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     peer @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@">=10.0.0" from @abp/ng.components@5.3.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@abp/ng.components
npm ERR!       @abp/ng.components@"~5.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@abp/ng.setting-management)
npm ERR!
....
```

What I am doing wrong? I just downloaded abp framework code from internet and run npm install but ended with this. What should i do?

Comment: you might need `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` or choose the correct dependency be installed.

Comment: I get same error while resolving angular-user-idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps one by one

1. Remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run again

> npm install

2. Or, try to clear npm cache

> npm cache clean --force

3. Or, run the command with the --legacy-peer-deps option

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

4. Or, run the command with the --force option

> npm install --force

Answer (score 1):

use the flag --legacy-peer-deps

```
npm install [package] --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-bootstrap@13.0.0 has exactly one dependancy. It's tslib. Which version are you using? Maybe try to update that.

Answer (score 0):

I found some github repo that says to use yarn instead of npm and it helps. Thank anyway :)

Comment: can you provide the link please